# Having trouble understanding part of my code, The Fisher–Yates shuffle

Tags: javascript

I'm learning about the "The Fisher Yates shuffle" and came across an issue. The part of my code that I've highlighted and commented "This Work", "This Doesn't Work" is to shuffle the array. From my understanding of Javascript, the part that doesn't work should work. Can you explain to me why it doesn't work?

```
const array = [..."12345678"]

let arrayShuffle = function(arr){


    for(let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1))
        let temp;

        let currentPos = arr[i] 
        let randomPos = arr[randomNum]

        /* This Work(it shuffled) \/ */
        temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[randomNum]
        arr[randomNum] = temp



        /* This Doesnt Work(Doesn't shuffle) \/ */
        // temp = currentPos
        // currentPos = randomPos
        // randomPos = temp
    }

    return arr
}

let res = arrayShuffle(array)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: assigning to variable and assigning at array element both are different.

Comment: @AmitVerma Hi i'm sorry for bothering you, i've just started learning javascript and i don't understand what you meant by assigning to variable and assigning to array element are different. if it's alright, can you elaborate it a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not work, because of `currentPos = arr[i]` and  `randomPos = arr[randomNum]`. Both of these are **copying** the values in arr, not the acctual pointer. Therefore, when you change `currentPos` or `randomPos` you are just changing a copy of whats actually in the array.

Take for example,

```
let x == 5
let y == x
y = y+1
console.log(x)
console.log(y)
```

`x = 5`
`y = 6`

The same thing is going on here. when we let y = x, it is only copying the value in x, and it is not an actual reference back to x. Therefore when we change y, we are **only** changing y, leaving x unaffected.